# Spacing after text in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

so I do not know why adding `padding` or even `margin` is not creating extra space after the text.

Output:

[image]

I want space after the `Stay Tuned` text and I tried adding `padding` and `margin` but it still did not work. What seems to be the issue? Any suggestions?

Code of that text:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
    background: transparent;
}

.title123 {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h23 {
    background-image: url(https://media.tenor.com/images/ad3dbde6dd7863faeb8151178df7bc71/tenor.gif);
    color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
}
/* styling my button */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/text.css">  
          <div class="title123">
 <h23>Stay Tuned!</h23>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paddings and margins applies to **block** elements. You need to make your `h23` element a block element - as it is not known HTML element it is rendered as inline by default.

You shouldn't use it at all ...but you can if you really want - just if you need padding or margin make it `block` or `inline-block` adding to your CSS a rule like this:

```
h23 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`h23` is not a HTML element. The heading tags are `h1-h6`. If you change it to `<h2>` it will work. Then you can add a class and target that.

```
<h2 class="h23">Stay tuned!<h2>
```

Then in your css file

```
.h23 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```